# Angular 2 aot cannot bind to X since it isn't a known property of Y

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular-ngmodel, angular-components

Refer to the code below, no matter I use `<dform [meta]="frmeta"></dform>` or `<dform meta="{{frmeta}}"></dform>` I'll get an error indicating

> Can't bind to 'meta' since it isn't a known property of 'dform'."

while compiling the typescript code.
Does any one know what's wrong with my code?

**DformComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, Attribute } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector:'dform',
    templateUrl:'DformComponent.html'
})
export class DformComponent{
  frmdata:any;

  constructor(fb:FormBuilder, @Attribute('meta') public meta:any){
    // this.frmdata = fb.group({
    //   phone:["123456789", containsMagicWord]
    //   , ip:["192.168.137.169", containsMagicWord]
    // });
    console.log(this.meta);
    debugger;
    this.frmdata = fb.group(this.meta);
  }

  dosubmit(event:any){
    console.log(this.frmdata.value);
  }
}
```

**DformComponent.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="frmdata" (submit)="dosubmit($event)">
    <inputmask formControlName="phone" mask="(___) ___ - ___"></inputmask>
    <inputmask formControlName="ip" mask="___.___.___.___" ></inputmask>
    <button type="submit">Post</button>
    <pre>{{ frmdata.value|json }}</pre>
</form>
```

**RootComponent.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

function containsMagicWord(c: any) {
  if(c.value.indexOf('magic') >= 0) {
    return {
      noMagic: true
    }
  }

  // Null means valid, believe it or not
  return null
}

@Component({
  selector: 'body',
  templateUrl: 'RootComponent.html'
})
export class RootComponent {
  frmeta:any = {
      phone:["123456789", containsMagicWord]
      , ip:["192.168.137.169", containsMagicWord]
  };
  constructor(){

  }
}
```

**RootComponent.html**

```
<dform meta="{{frmeta}}"></dform>
```

Comment: Please add the exact error message. `X` and `Y` are not helpful.

Comment: Added, please check.

Comment: What's the intention or expected behavior of `[meta]="frmeta"`?

Comment: I planned to create form elements dynamically.  RootComponent.meta contains exactly the same code as the commented code above console.log(this.meta) 
An object will be passed from RootComponent to the DformComponent to build the form using FormBuilder.

Comment: But what is `[meta]="frmeta"` supposed to do. The component doesn't have an `@Input() meta;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `DformComponent` to

```
@NgModule({
  ...,
  declarations: [DformComponent]
```

and the component needs an

```
@Input() meta:SomeType;
```

for

```
[meta]="frmeta"
```

to be valid.